# How to avoid stop script error in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-7

I have a page of more than 2500 anchor tag to process. Now in IE it is throwing the stop script error. Is it possible to do as a batch? Taking 500 executing it and then take the another 500 executing it??

This is the code...

```
ajaxLinks : function(el, flag) {
    var links = $(el).find('a');
    var notLinkAr=["a[href^=javascript]","#toolbarId ul li>a","#tool_settings .link a",".page-action-links li>a","#tool_settings .label a",".success-map .success-tabs li>a",".success-map .sm_loggedin li>a", ".analyst_cat li>a",".modal",".layer",".newpage",".close",".hideFromPopup",".pagenum",".next",".prev",".delete_src",".tips","#hidr","#backr"];
    $(notLinkAr).each(function(index){
        var notLinkI=$(notLinkAr[index]);
        if($(notLinkI).is("a")){
            if($(notLinkI).length>0){
                $(notLinkI).each(function(index1){
                        $(notLinkI[index1]).addClass("dontAjaxify");
                });
            }
        }
    });
     $(links).each(function(i, obj){
        var link = $(obj);
        if(!$(obj).hasClass('dontAjaxify')){
           link.attr('rel', link.attr('href'));
            var rellnk = link.attr('rel');
            if(flag=='ajaxified') {
                if(/http/.test(rellnk)){
                    var relurl;
                    relurl=rellnk.replace((window.location.protocol + "//"+ window.location.hostname),'')
                    link.attr('rel', relurl);;
                }
            }
            link.bind('click', function(e){}
```

Iam adding a class for all the anchor tag(which is 2500) in a page.

Comment: what script is running against the a tag??

Comment: please add sm code.. the question is abstract otherwise...

Comment: 2500 anchor tags? Do you really need that many? Maybe use pagination to reduce the load per page?

Comment: That is the requirement. The client doesn't want pagination or any other. Is their a way to split the anchore to some number say 500 in the first set to process and then taking the rest??

Comment: In my experience, many links are good, too many links, not as much. I consider any website with more then 300 links to not be constructed properly. You should try to explain to your client that producing so many links on one webpage will cause it to run slowly, also with so many links on that page, it may not be clear to the user where he wants to go. You should take that into account.

Comment: Also, AJAXing for the sake of AJAXing is not considered very good generally, let alone on a webpage with 2,500 links.

Comment: But if you insists... how about adding a class to the <a>'s server side, and limiting the class to ~500 items?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's .slice may help you.
http://api.jquery.com/slice/

```
var count = 0;
var ajaxify = function (el, flags) {
    var links = $(el).find('a').slice(count, count + 500);
    count = count + 500;

    // Do the processing here

    if (links.length) {
       // Call it next time only if some data is returned in the current call
       setTimeout("ajaxify()", 5000);
    }
}
```

The above code is not tested, but should probably work.

Comment: In addition, you can also make a few changes to increase the performance.
For ex: 
1. Instead of running a loop over all the 'links' and then applying an if condition, you can use selectors to get only those links with the required class. such as: var links = $(el).find('a.dontAjaxify');
2. addClass() can directly be applied to the complete set. So, there is no need for .each(). You can have $(notLinkI).addClass("dontAjaxify")

Comment: As far as I know, the `...slice(count, count+499)` should read `count+500`, since the end argument is described as _up to but not including element_. So, for elements 0 -> 499 (inclusive), you need `slice(0, 500)`.

Comment: Thanks @GKelly for noticing the typo. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Rather than using `setTimeout("ajaxify()", 5000);`, use `setTimeout(ajaxify, 5000);`. Passing a string to `setTimeout` is just a glorified `eval`.